# Move semantics behaving unexpectedly

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code, the assertion in `foo` is failing:

```
void bar (std::shared_ptr<int> && value) {
}

void foo () {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    bar(std::move(ptr));
    assert(ptr == nullptr);
}
```

The shared pointer still points to the value 5 after the call to `bar`. I expected the call to `bar` to use move semantics, leaving `ptr` null.

Where is the flaw in my understanding?

Comment: Where are you expecting it to move to exactly?

Comment: `std::move()` declaration: `template< class T > constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t );`  Return value: `static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)`  Uses perfect forwarding to take `t` by reference or rvalue reference, and casts it to rvalue reference.

Answer (score 8):

Essentially, `std::move()` is just a cast.

Change `bar()` to see the result you desire.

```
void bar (std::shared_ptr<int> && value)
{
   std::shared_ptr<int> v{std::move(value)};
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The pointer will become null after you perform the actual move. `std::move` by itself does not move anything. It simply makes it possible to pass a *named* object `ptr` to an rvalue-reference-expecting function.

Since you don't actually move anything inside that function (or anywhere else), the pointer remains unmoved-from.

Do this (for one example)

```
void bar (std::shared_ptr<int> && value) {
  std::shared_ptr<int> another_ptr(std::move(value));
}
```

and you'll see your original pointer moved.